# Realm installation XCode 8.1

Tags: ios, xcode, realm

I struggle with integrating Realm in my project.
Actually, I'm following guidelines from official documentation, though that doesn't help me.

While I'm trying to import RealmSwift I got "No such module".

```
import RealmSwift
```

In framework Realm.framework is red.

[image]

Here is my Podfile

```
    # Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'RealmTest' do
  # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for RealmTest
  pod 'RealmSwift'

  target 'RealmTestTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'RealmTestUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end

  post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '2.3' # or '3.0'
      # Pods for testing
       end
     end
   end
end
```

Comment: Can you try moving the `post_install` portion of the Podfile out of the `target 'RealmTest' do` part, and then running `pod install` from the terminal again?

Comment: @AustinZ didn't help either

Comment: Can you build and run your proyect? That may solve the issue. The first time you compile the project, even if it's correctly installed, you get this error.

Comment: @Orlando That didn't help, but is figured out the main mistake. It is crushes because module compiled with Swift 2.3 cannot be imported in Swift 3.

Comment: @DanielChepenko Why are you using Swift 2.3 in XCode 8.1? It will not work.

Answer (score 1):

I had some issues getting it installed as well. This may not be the answer but after working through these, my project is building:

Here's my PodFile which is similar

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'RealmTest' do
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for RealmTest
  pod ‘RealmSwift’

end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.0'
    end
  end
end
```

I had to update CocoaPods

```
$ sudo gem install cocoapods
```

then install Realm again, quit Xcode then

```
pod install
```

from there use the

```
.xcworkspace
```

file generated by CocoaPods to open the project.

And the last item was to manually add two files to the Linked Frameworks and Libraries section.

Open your project via the .xcworkspace, select your project in the left column. Then select General on the right and scroll down the Linked Frameworks and Libraries and add these two files

```
Realm.framework
RealmSwift.framework
```

That last step seems unnecessary but we could not get the build to work until we did that step.

Answer (score 1):

Oh!
Actually the problem was in Swift Compiler - Version
Who would have similar problem, try to go to Build Settings - Swift Compiler - Version - Use Legacy Swift Language Version - Switch it to "No"